# How to test a functionality split in microservices

Tags: php, kubernetes, testing, microservices

I have a functionallity that is slit in 3 microservices that are run with kubernetes. Depending on the input of the first, the second does things and automatically creates a kubernette to process the last result.

I want to make a test to check the whole process, but I can't figure the way to do this. I'm thinking that this may break some testing principle...

Do anyone has done something similar that give some advice?

Regards.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should test each microservice by themselves without actually calling each other. If you want to test the second microservice, you should mock the response from the first, and then validate that your service does what is expected based on the mocked response

Comment: Yes. I was thinking that was the correct way to implement this tests. Thank you Ebski.